# Intercept HTTP response with CXF

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm using CXF as SOAP framework.
I've both server and client interfaces for synchronous and asynchronous calls.

What I need is intercept the HTTP response. More in detail:

- For server interface (two way - sync):
  I need to intercept the client HTTP response (i.e. 200 if everything is fine)
- For Client interface (one way - no soap reponse):
  Similar as above, I need to intercept the server HTTP response

I've tried to configure both inInterceptor and outInterceptor, but I can only see the inBound and outBound soap messages. Instead what I need is see the HTTP response on outBound messages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean, @InInterceptor and @OutInterceptor? What do you need HTTP headers for? If server returns 500, for example, you have the Exception.

Comment: Yes. I can handle an Exception and see the return code. 
I would like do the same in case of success when any exception isn't thrown (i.e. for every 2xx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ReadHeadersInterceptor?
Have you tried Intercepters by adding them programmatically and through configuration.
Examples here - http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

If you are really after HTTP headers and not SOAP, then you might not need SOAP to do it. You can read them directly. Check these examples

- http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-response-header-in-java/
- [Getting raw HTTP response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307291/getting-raw-http-response-headers)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not too late for the answer :-)

I encounter the same problem and after debuging I found out that a CXF client runs interceptors before reading response entity from input stream.
So the only way to get reponse is:

```
InputStream is = inMessage.getContent(InputStream.class)
```

And read and marshall to proper response.