# Android/Java: how to know what is the type of a remote audio streaming file ?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I have to connect to many different types of live audio streaming files. These files can be mp3, AAC, ogg, etc... but the urls do not give any information about the type of file. For example, I have got urls like "http://www.asite.com/astreamingfile" and not something like "http://www.asite.com/astreamingfile.mp3" or "http://www.asite.com/astreamingfile.aac".

How can I know the type audio streaming file behind an url ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

General URL like http://www.asite.com/astreamingfile will either be an alias or provide some kind of detection mechanism but at the end point to a valid mp3, AAC ... URL.

You can can check for the HTTP response header of http://www.asite.com/astreamingfile and see if you have a "Content-Type audio/mp3" header (or another format). You can parse in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307291/getting-raw-http-response-headers) for that information and so determine what kind of file you are dealing with.