# How to get website header all of them in android using HttpURLconnection?

Tags: android, html, header, httpurlconnection

I am developing an android application as personal project. and I want to get Html header data from a website. but I can't get header data I want. I think because header's name is declared twice, and the data I want is included into second header'name. though I want to get all of header data, I can't get the data using HttpURLconnection's API I know.

Can I get these data by other way?

Comment: Take a look at this StackOverflow question and its answers: [Getting raw HTTP response headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307291/getting-raw-http-response-headers).

Comment: @JonnyHenly Thanks! :)