# Why does URLConnection.getInputStream() not include the HTTP response headers?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, java-io

I use this.

```
public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.icourse163.org/passport/reg/icourseLogin.do";

public static void loginSimulation() throws IOException {
    URL loginUrl = new URL(LOGIN_URL);
    URLConnection connection = loginUrl.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.icourse163.org/member/logout.htm");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    PrintWriter loginDataWriter = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

    String loginData = "returnUrl=aHR0cDovL2ljb3Vyc2UxNjMub3JnLw%3D%3D&failUrl=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5pY291cnNlMTYzLm9yZy9tZW1iZXIvbG9naW4uaHRtP2VtYWlsRW5jb2RlZD1PVGM1TnpJME9EZ3lRSEZ4TG1OdmJRPT0%3D&savelogin=false&oauthType=&username=979724882%40qq.com";
    loginDataWriter.print(loginData);
    loginDataWriter.flush();



    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        builder.append(line);
    }
```

But the `builder.toString` did not have any information about the response headers? I think there is a pipe between my client and the server. So all of the response should come through this pipe (including the response headers, response content etc). But the result is not. Why?

Comment: I think you'll find `connection` has already got all the header information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting raw HTTP response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307291/getting-raw-http-response-headers)

Comment: Can you tell us what `connection` is i.e. it's fully qualified class name?

Comment: @SteveSmith Did I think wrong? I think the HTTP process is that the client send the request headers to the server and the server send send the response to the client all through the connection? So the connection.getInputStream should hava all the response data(including the response headers、response content etc)

Comment: `URLConnection` reads all the headers automatically (it needs them to know what to do).  `getInputStream()` is only for reading the "body", e.g. the HTML or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the type of `connection` is (`HttpUrlConnection`, `URLConnection` etc), it will provide an accessor for headers. Have a look for methods named `*.eaders.*`, for example: `getHeaderFields()`.

By contrast, `getInputStream()` will likely only be reading the response body.

**Edit 1**: based on your updated question it is clear that you are using `java.net.URLConnection` so my original answer stands: `getInputStream()` is only reading the response body and you'll get the HTTP response headers from `getHeaderFields()`.

The revised question also makes clear that you are interested not just in **how** to get the headers but in **why** the headers are not availabe in the InputStream. There is a library between your client and the raw HTTP response and that library has decided to present the raw response to you in this way: (1) the response body as an `InputStream`; (2) the headers as a `Map<String,List<String>>`. That's a choice made in the implementation of that library. So, as long as you use `java.net.URLConnection` this is how you must consume the response. FWIW, other libraries (such as Apache Commons' HttpClient) do much the same thing.

Comment: you seems right.I am just a little confused...I just think all the response data can get by the `connection.getInputStream`..Because the returned inputStream by  `connection.getInputStream` represents the pipeline.

Comment: There is a library between your client and the raw HTTP response and that library (`java.net`, in this case) has decided to present the raw response to you in this way: (1) the response body as an `InputStream`; (2) the headers as a `Map<String,List<String>>`. So, as long as you use `java.net.URLConnection` this is how you must consume the response. FWIW, other libraries (such as Apache Commons' HttpClient) do much the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

you should use getHeaderFields to obtain response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try it like this.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the HTTP process is that the client send the request headers to the server and the server send send the response to the client all through the connection? So the connection.getInputStream should hava all the response data(including the response headers、response content etc) ..your code did not return any of the response headers.So the response headers did not use the pip between the client and server?

Comment: The conn.getHeaderField("CustomHeader") returns the response header not the request one.

To return the request header use: conn.getRequestProperty("CustomHeader")